# Inconsistency in Star Trek TNG holodeck

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I’m rewatching TNG, and twice have noticed that objects from the holodeck are able to exit the holodeck. Wesley gets wet and stays wet when leaving; and also has a snowball fight, throwing a snowball which exits the holodeck and hits Captain Picard. How?

Answer (score 1):

Holograms can't exit the holodecks on the Enterprise-D, since they require holo-emitters to exist, and there aren't any in the corridors of that vessel.

Holodecks are apparently capable of transporting and/or replicating *real* matter, however; Data intimated as much in one of the scenes you cited (the one with Wesley Crusher, from *[Encounter at Farpoint](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint_(episode))*):

> **Riker:** "I didn't believe these simulations could be this real."
>
> **Data:** "Much of it *is* real, sir. If the transporters can convert our bodies to an energy beam, then back to the original pattern..."
>
> **Riker:** "Yes, of course; then these rocks and vegetations have much simpler patterns."
>
> **Data:** "Correct, sir."

So apparently, the water Wesley was drenched with was real, non-holographic matter (and I'm guessing the same thing applied to the snowball).

Comment: There are also numerous scenes where people eat and drink in holographic bars and restaurants, which would lend weight to the "replicator" theory.